# How to get String data from a running JVM by using AJAX to display it on html?

Tags: java, ajax, string, stream, jvm

This is my JVM code which loops forever.

```
public String getValue(String fieldName)
{
    String value = null;
    if (_record != null)
    {
        if (_active)
        {
            if (_hasData)
            {
                String field = (String)_record.get(fieldName);

                if (field != null)
                    value = field;
                else
                    value = "XX";
            }
            else
                value = "Pending";
        }
        else
            value = "Inactive";
    }
    else
    {
        value = "";
    }
    return value;
}
```

The problem is how can I get the String of the 'value' and send it to my AJAX so I can stream it on my html without saving to database?

Thank you.

Comment: very unclear question. You will not receive answers

Answer (score 0):

First, how do you invoke this ?
If you are using AJAX, this needs to be behind a servlet which is hosted on some server.

Or are you connecting via sockets ?

Please elaborate...

Comment: I am working on a project by feeding data through the Thomson Reuters. I have no problem on getting the value from their server. But the problem is while this data feeding program is running, is it possible for me to get the value of the data from running another new program like AJAX?

Comment: Can u give a little idea about the components involved. As in, where is this program running ? From where do you want to extract data (the string that is returned) You could alternately write this data to some database. Have another servlet read from that database. Call this servlet using AJAX from the browser...